# Why 'Meta'? Why not 'Bobcat'?

Tags: discussion, meta

I understand what the Meta sites are, their purpose in life, and their importance, however I do not understand fully why they have the name 'Meta'? I mean, why not 'Bobcat'? Could some please explain?

Comment: This belongs on meta.so I think, because they came up with it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Citing from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta):

> Meta (from the Greek preposition and prefix meta- (μετά-) meaning "after", or "beyond") is a prefix used in English to indicate a concept which is an abstraction from another concept, used to complete or add to the latter.

The English usage for *meta* is more in the direction of "about", hence [meta.askubuntu.com](https://meta.askubuntu.com/) is the site where you talk **about** the site [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/)